# Change a div's background when the span inside that div contains specific text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these 3 divs:

```
<div class="price"><span>Free</span> </div><br/>

<div class="price"><span>$250 USD</span> </div><br/>

<div class="price"><span>$800 USD</span> </div>
```

The background of the divs are red by default and i want to change it to green when the span of that divs contain the word "Free".

What i tried already is this code:

```
$('.price > span').each(function(){
  if ($('.price > span').text()==="Free"){
    $('.price').css('background-color', 'green');
  }
})
```

Why it doesn't work?

My [FIDDLE IS HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/1maewneu/20/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your selector is grabbing more than a single element , when you are using `.each()` inside it's scope you can use `this` to refer to the current element that's being iterated:

```
$('.price > span').each(function(){
  if($(this).text()==="Free"){
    $(this).parent(".price").css('background-color', 'green');
  }
});
```

[*Updated Fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/1maewneu/33/)

Comment: Thanks for answering but your solution is changing the background color of the span and not the background of the whole div

Comment: @Designer My bad, miss-read your inner selector when I made this. You just need to grab the parent `.price` (by doing: `$(this).parent(".price")`) of that element. Updated my answer.

Comment: thank u so much. "parent" is what i was missing. Now it works perfect, i ll select your answer as the best.

Answer (score 0):

Spencer's looks good. If you want to do it without jquery, you can do it like this

https://jsfiddle.net/1maewneu/38/

```
document.querySelectorAll('.price > span').forEach(function(span) {
    span.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = span.innerText === 'Free'
    ? 'green'
    : null
})
```